# How to ORDER BY with different columns / criteria as one column?

Tags: php

I've got the following code below: and I want to order the query results in different way.

```
$db = $this->database[GDB];
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT TOP 100 strUserId, TotalTime, Nation, LoginDT FROM USERDATA WHERE Authority IN(1, 2) ORDER BY TotalTime DESC');
if ($num_rows == -1)
{
$db->getError();
return;
}
```

**What I want to do is the following:**

`ORDER BY` like that:

```
TotalTime + (time() + 7200 - LoginDT) DESC // this doesnt work for some reason, no error message but it doesnt select any ... so there must be something wrong?
```

How I can do that in the query above?

**I use MSSQL Server 2005**

EDIT:

```
......
 $db->doQuery('INSERT INTO Competition (AID, TimeRaffle, TRaffle, TicketNum) VALUES (?, ?, GetDate(), ?)', $_SESSION['Acc'], time(), $ticket);
......
```

Comment: what if you put the whole order by calculation in brackets?  ( TotalTime + (time() + 7200 - LoginDT) )

Comment: Please edit the original question rather than posting the same question twice.